# How to move a perforce depot between two different servers such that revision history is copied but user info and workspaces are not?

Tags: perforce

I need to copy a depot from one Perforce server to another. The file revision history needs to be intact but the user information and workspace information can not be copied to the new server.

I've tried a standard checkpoint creation and restore procedure, but if there exist users or workspaces with the same name on both servers, the source server will overwrite this info on the destination server. This is pretty bad if those user accounts and workspaces do not have exactly identical details.

The goal of this sort of operation is to allow two separate, disconnected groups to view a versioned source tree with revision history. Updates would be single directional with one group developing and one just viewing. Each group's network is completely enclosed, no outside connections of any kind.

Any ideas would be appreciated, i've been busting my brains on this one for a while.

EDIT:
Ultimately my solution was to install an intermediate Perforce server on the same machine as my source server. Using that I could do a standard backup/restore from the source server to the intermediate server and then delete all unwanted meta data in the intermediate server before backing up from the intermediate server to the final destination server. Pretty complicated but it got the job done and it can all be done programatically in Windows Power Shell.

Comment: Did you consider migrating to `git` ???

Comment: The specific need was explained in good detail. I can't see how suggesting a different source-control tool solves this problem.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways, but I think you are going about this one the hard way.

1. Continue to do what you are doing, but delete the db.user, db.view(I think) and db.group. Then when you start the perforce server, it will create these, but they will be empty, which will make it hard for anyone to log in. So you'll have to create users/groups. I'm not sure if you can take those db files from another server and copy them in, never tried that.
2. The MUCH easier way, make a replica. http://www.perforce.com/perforce/r10.2/manuals/p4sag/10_replication.html Make sure you look at the p4d -M flag to make sure it's a read only replica. I assume you have a USB drive or something to move between networks, so you can just issue a p4 pull onto the USB drive, then move the drive, and either run it off the USB, or issue another p4 pull, pulling to a final server. Never tried this, but with some work it should be possible, you'll have to run a server off the USB to issue the final p4 pull.
3. You could take a look at perforce git fusion, and make some git clones.

Comment: #2 is definitely a good resource to have, but the problem I am faced with in regards to replicating a server at all(read only or otherwise) is that user and workspace information is disjoint and needs to remain so. IE a user profile from the target should not be recreated on the source during this process, additionally, if there are two like named users or workspaces the details of the one residing on the target can't overwrite the one on the source.

Answer (score 1):

You could also look at remote depots. Basically you create a new depot on your destination server, and point it at a depot on your source server. This works if you have a fast connection between the 2 servers. Protections are handled by the destination server, as to who has access to that new depot. The source server can be set up to share it out as read only to the destination server. Here is some info

http://answers.perforce.com/articles/KB_Article/Creating-A-Remote-Depot

Just make sure you test it during a slow period, as it can slow down the destination server. I tried it from 2 remote locations, both on the east coast US, and it was acceptable, but not too useful. If both servers are in the same building it would be fine.