# Perforce. Copy from one server to another

Tags: perforce

We have two perforce servers. I need to copy everything from depot on one server to depot on another server. The [copy](http://www.perforce.com/perforce/r14.2/manuals/cmdref/p4_copy.html) command doesn't take into account different servers.

Is it possible?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to move a perforce depot between two different servers such that revision history is copied but user info and workspaces are not?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13238503/how-to-move-a-perforce-depot-between-two-different-servers-such-that-revision-hi)

Comment: @rave I don't need to move the users and workspaces. I only need to copy data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't mention if you just need the head revisions or if you need full history, whether this is a one-time request or part of a regular process, whether both servers are under your control, etc.

So some of this is speculation, but here's three possible ways:

1. Create a workspace for each server, both pointing to the same place on your workstation. Sync the files from the source server, then submit them to the target server.
2. Create a remote depot on the target server, pointing to the source server. Then integrate the files from the remote depot to their desired location in the target server.
3. Use the P4Transfer utility: https://swarm.workshop.perforce.com/projects/perforce-software-p4transfer/

If none of these seem appropriate for you, perhaps you have special needs. There are a number of other options available, including special tools that need some assistance to use, but if you find you have such custom needs you should contact Perforce Technical Support for more precise guidance.

Comment: Thank you. Remote depot is good for me. Just for curiosity - is moving a history possible? Following the link from first comment to question doesn't helped me - it seems complicated. I don't have an access to server or db. I'm just a user with admin rights. So is it possible for me to keep a history?

Comment: If the history is important, you can certainly keep it. P4Transfer does an excellent job of preserving history. There are other tools such as perfmerge that can do this, and there are other possibilities, but for some of those very specialized tools I'd really advise you to contact Perforce Technical Support as some of them are a bit complex to operate.

Comment: I agree that the specialized tools (such as Perfmerge++) are tricky to operate, but at least the documentation is pretty clear. P4Transfer's documentation appears to be written for people who already know exactly what P4Transfer does exactly, which I don't and can't tell from the documentation. For example, the word "history" literally appears only once within in P4Transfer's doc file, in one of the introductory paragraphs:


"You may also wish to consolidate various Perforce servers into one with all their history."


There is no further context. Bizarre.